# Closing a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a jtable. For every row of this table (when I select it) I need to open a new jframe.
After I open the application, I do a simple search using a button and I select a row for the first time, it works ok;
the problem starts when I close this new jframe just opened I execute another search and I select
another row; in practice more than one jframe with the same content is opened. It is like more than one request is sent.

This code is in the main app:

```
private static String QUERY_BASED_ON_SITE2="from WordsToFind a where a.wordToFindName like '";

private void runQueryBasedOnName2() {
     executeHQLQuery2(QUERY_BASED_ON_SITE2 + jTextField14.getText() + "%'");
}

private void executeHQLQuery2(String hql2) {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Query q2 = session.createQuery(hql2);
        List resultsWords2 = (List) q2.list();
        System.out.println("resultsWords2 ----> " + resultsWords2);
        displayWords2(resultsWords2);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(!jTextField14.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        runQueryBasedOnName2();
    }        

}

private void displayWords2(List resultsWords2) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {                       
        Vector<String> tableHeaders2 = new Vector<String>();
        final Vector tableWords2 = new Vector();   
        tableHeaders2.add("Word Id");
        for(Object ow : resultsWords2) {
              WordsToFind words;
              words = (WordsToFind)ow;
              Vector<Object> oneRowWords = new Vector<Object>();
              oneRowWords.add(words.getWordToFindId());
              tableWords2.add(oneRowWords);
                        }     
    jTable4.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableWords2, tableHeaders2));         
    jTable4.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    jTable4.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jTable4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
              public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {      
                int selectedRow = jTable4.getSelectedRow();                                
                selectedRow = jTable4.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
                SimpleSwingBrowser browser = new SimpleSwingBrowser();
                browser.setVisible(true);                                                              
                browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
                browser.highlihtWord();                                                          
                }
              });
}
```

I tried adding the follwing line of code into the SimpleSwingBrowser class

and

```
dispose();
```

also

`this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

I obtained the same results.
Thanks Alb

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is happening when you close jframe? How many Frames open when you click a row?

Comment: Can you show some more code? Your methods should work.

Comment: Do you really need to open a JFrame, or do you need a JWindow??

Comment: You would use a modal JDialog as a popup, not a JFrame. `It is like more than one request is sent.` - Sounds to me like you keep adding the ActionListener to your button. In any case the problem is with your code, not Swing. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem if you need more help.

Comment: I modified the question with some more details. p.s. that the problem is in my code is certain ;)Thanks Alb

Comment: *"that the problem is in my code is certain"*  1) Someone that cannot explain the behavior of the code cannot be sure that the (uncompilable) code (snippets) provided includes the vital code. 2) We cannot compile and run the code to test it and try things. -- Please follow the advice of @camickr and post code we can work with.

Comment: @camickr this is the code reduced to the minimun, I hope you can help me because I cannot really find my error. Thanks Alb

Comment: That is not a SSCCE so no I can't help. I can't compile that code. I don't have access to you database etc. A SSCCE demonstrates the concept. You problem is with opening multiple frames when you click on a button. So demonstrate the problem with an example. While you attempt to create the example you will probably find your problem.

Comment: @camickr, I finally found what was wrong, you told me that in the beginning, but because of my inattention it took me sometimes finding it. In practice, I had to move: setAutoCreateRowSorter, setSelectionMode and addMouseListener out of the jButton. Thanks Alb

Comment: Will you answer control.

Comment: @gocan76  if so please accept/vote it

Answer (score 1):

The JFrame gets the event to close and upon closing, exits.

```
    JFrame frame= new JFrame()
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // frame code here ..
    frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default operation to exit on close would work. Make sure to set that for the jframes you intend to close

```
JFrame frame= new JFrame()
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Using `dipose()` for the jframe you open on click could also work

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/notes/chap56/ch56_9.html

Comment: Uhmmm, he said he's using dispose and it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume he's using Dipose of the main frame, not the one being opened, hard to tell if there is no code.

Comment: @Chen dispose is the one being opened

Comment: try `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));` else `setVisible(false);` but that just hides the frame

Comment: unfortunately same behaviour

Comment: something is wrong with your code then, those are the definite and easiest fixes to that kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

When you create new `JFrames` from your current `JFrame` , make sure it has this piece of code

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

`Note` : Don't make new `JFrames` of same `class` , create a seperate exteneded `JFrame` for that.

Answer (score 0):

a bit of code would be very helpful to debug your problem. 
I think you should name the instance to null when you are using method

`dispose()`

please let me know if this help you. or if you get solution please share with us. thanks bro

Comment: Random guesses are just 'noise' until we find out more about the problem. *"a bit of code would be very helpful"* The OP has already posted 'a bit of code'.  What we need is an **MCVE or SSCCE.**